# Liferay 6: Portlet View in MAXIMIZED State

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Once the request is made to the MVCPortlet class , i want to show the View in MAXIMIZED State .
This is my Code in JSP Page

```jsp
<portlet:actionURL  name="addBook" var="addBookURL" />
<aui:form action="<%= addBookURL.toString() %>" method="post">
    <aui:input type="text" name="name"></aui:input>
    <aui:input type="password" name="pwd"></aui:input>
    <aui:button type="submit"></aui:button>
</aui:form>
```

This is my MVCPortlet class :

```java
if(true)
        {

             response.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);
            response.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED);

        }

        else
        {

             response.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);
            response.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED);

        }
```

And this is the result (Please see the image below )

[image]

My question is that , i was expecting that once the Action class is called , so the Portlet will be displayed in MAXIMIZED State .

But still the Portlet remains in NORMAL State , please let me know why ?and how can i Portlet View in MAXIMIZED State after the result from MVCPortlet class .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two possibilities how to display portlet in maximized mode. You either add windowState parameter with value maximized to the actionURL tag (it will allways show the link to portlet in maximized state), or you put this line

```
response.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED);
```

into processAction method of your portlet (you can make a decision based on something).

(this is what specification says, but Liferay usually adheres to it).

Comment: That was working when  i restarted the machine . not even the server . anyway Thanks .